# How to increase quota limit for number of build triggers in GCP project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are using google cloud build for our CI/CD and currently, we almost hit the limit on the number of build triggers. From this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/quotas#increasing_quota), it should be possible to increase the limit of build triggers number. [image] . However, we couldn't find the quota limit for this item on this [page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?service=cloudbuild.googleapis.com). So our question is simple, if the number of build triggers can be increased then where we can change this?

Comment: Yes, the quota can be increased in the Google Cloud Console. Your question provides the link (#1) to request a quota increase. What problem are you having with increasing that quota?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I am not able to find the quota named `trigger` in the [Quota console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas), I suggest you contact Google Support as mentioned in the [Quotas document](https://cloud.google.com/build/quotas).

> If the Cloud Console does not let you request a change for a specific
> quota, contact [Google Cloud support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs).